# Linkedin Sales Navigator Initially Installed for Admins But now want installed for all Users

Tags: linkedin

I initially chose to install LinkedIn Sales Navigator app for our Admins, but now I want to install it for all users. How do I do this without having to uninstall everything and re-install?

Comment: Have you looked at assigning licenses for the app to the users that you'd like to have access? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_managing_licenses.htm&type=5